# How to run python post hoc test?

Tags: python

I would like to know how post hoc tests are performed with Python 
(I have estimated a parameter by different independent experiments, obtaining a value with uncertainty from each fit).
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you looking into the `statsmodels` package? Something like `statsmodels.stats.multicomp.pairwise_tukeyhsd` (https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.stats.multicomp.pairwise_tukeyhsd.html) might be what you need